# Automated httr authentication with twitteR , provide response to interactive prompt in "batch" mode

Tags: r, twitter-oauth, batch-processing

I am using the R package twitteR to post items to Twitter.  I put everything inside of a function and it works fine.  However, I would like to run the function without being prompted for a response, and I haven't figured out how to do that.  Any suggestions?

Here are the bare bones of my function:

```
doit <- function(<snip>) {
    <snip>
    # connect to Twitter
    setup_twitter_oauth(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
    <snip>
    }
```

When I run the function from the command line, I am prompted for an interactive response.

```
[1] "Using direct authentication"
Use a local file to cache OAuth access credentials between R sessions?
1: Yes
2: No

Selection:
```

I can provide this information directly in a script when the setup_twitter_oauth() function is outside of a function, by entering my response in the following line, much like can be done for other user input functions like readline() or scan().

```
setup_twitter_oauth(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
1
```

However, I haven't been able to get this approach to work when setup_twitter_oauth() is INSIDE of a function.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to get this to run without requiring user input.

=====

The answer from @NicE below did the trick.  I incorporated the options setting in my function as:

```
doit <- function(<snip>) {
    <snip>
    # connect to Twitter
    origop <- options("httr_oauth_cache")
    options(httr_oauth_cache=TRUE)
    setup_twitter_oauth(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
    options(httr_oauth_cache=origop)
    <snip>
    }
```

Comment: Your question ended up helping me. Since i just wanted to pass the selection (1) outside an function. Thanks!

Comment: I couldn't got an error trying your code with the <snip> part. What do you suggest I replace that with?

Comment: The `<snip>` is not actual R code, it's just my shorthand way of indicating that in my script I've removed some other code (not relevant to the question) for clarity.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try setting the `httr_oauth_cache` option to TRUE:

```
options(httr_oauth_cache=T)
```

The twitteR package uses the `httr` package, on the `Token` manual page for that package they give tips about caching:

```
OAuth tokens are cached on disk in a file called .httr-oauth 
saved in the current working directory. Caching is enabled if:

The session is interactive, and the user agrees to it, OR

The .httr-oauth file is already present, OR

getOption("httr_oauth_cache") is TRUE

You can suppress caching by setting the httr_oauth_cache option to FALSE.
```

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly fine.

```
install.packages("twitteR", dependencies = T)
install.packages(c('ROAuth','RCurl'))
install.packages("httr")
library(httr)
require('ROAuth')
require('RCurl')
library(twitteR)



reqURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"

accessURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"

authURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"

consumerKey <- "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"

consumerSecret <- "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

twitCred <-     OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,consumerSecret=consumerSecret,requestURL=reqURL,accessURL=accessURL,authURL=authURL)

download.file(url="https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem", destfile="cacert.pem")

 twitCred$handshake(cainfo="cacert.pem")

  setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know much about it.

But if it's in batch, maybe try this:

```
doit <- function(<snip>) {
    <snip>
    # connect to Twitter
    setup_twitter_oauth(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
    < echo 1
    <snip>
}
```

Also have you tried posting the `1` outside the function to see if it does the same?

And maybe it will work if you put the `1` under the `snip`

These are just suggestions, cause i don't know very much about the topic, but it might help though.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the `< echo 1` line.  The `<` is a relational operator.  And I know of no function with the name `echo`.  When I pasted it in, I got `Error: unexpected '<' in:
"setup_twitter_oauth(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
<"`.  I also tried your suggestion of putting the `1` under the `snip`.  That didn't work.  I will try the `1` outside of the function next.

Comment: Probably a good idea to test your solution before posting it as an answer, especially if you "don't know much about the subject"...

Comment: @nrussel I was just trying to help, it might have worked, but i guess it isn't batch. Sorry it was stupid of me trying to help withouth knowing much about it.

Comment: That's what comments are for.

Comment: @nrussell I don't have enough reputation yet, to post comments