# automatically answer a selection in R

Tags: r, twitter-r

I'm using the twitteR package in R. When it's authenticating, it asks:

```
[1] "Using direct authentication"
Use a local file to cache OAuth access credentials between R sessions?
1: Yes
2: No
```

Is there a way to automatically set this to No? It'll be on a webserver so the user won't have the option to set this.

This is called by:

```
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key = "<redacted>", consumer_secret = "<redacted>", 
                    access_token="<redacted>", access_secret="<redacted>")
```

Comment: What function are you calling that brings up this message? Show the code that generates this prompt.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28221405/automated-httr-authentication-with-twitter-provide-response-to-interactive-pro/28332136#28332136) answer